# after comping redis 2.2.5 redis-stat is not created

Tags: redis

I wget the latest version of redis 2.2.5, then make, and cd redis-2.2.5/src, but there is no redis-stat found. Why?

Could someone tell me the reason? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find answer in google groups, since the redis-stat is moved to another seperate project in hithub: https://github.com/antirez/redis-tools/